# How can I get internet and Bluetooth working in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, 17.04

I've already read and tried various solutions that apply here, but none have worked for me.

I have an Asus that came with Windows 8.1. I installed Ubuntu 17.04, but now it's asking me to change the kernel, and I can't connect to the internet to do so.

What can I do?

This is the result of running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e074]
03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [1043:165d]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](/q/377050/175814)

Answer (score 0):

There is a network manager file in 17.04 that blocked my system from automatically managing my devices, located here:

`/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`

Content:

```
[keyfile]

unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

I commented it all out, rebooted, and everything works fine now. It can also be deleted. Let me know if this helps.